# error while creating Postgres extension www_fdw

Tags: postgresql, foreign-data-wrapper, postgresql-extensions

I want to use www_fdw extension of PostgreSQL in order to read data from web services.  I used this command to create extension:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS www_fdw CASCADE
```

but it gives me following error:

> could not open extension control file "C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/PostgreSQL/9.6/share/extension/www_fdw.control": No such file or
>   directory

I am working in Windows.

Any idea whats the reason for error?

Comment: Did you you download and install the `www_fdw` extension? It is not part of a default installation

Comment: change directory to `contrib` and repeat `make` and `make install`

Comment: Do you have a compatible development environment to build extensions? Do you have a C compiler? Did you install cygwin? Otherwise you can't use the commands that are intended for Linux.

Comment: You will need a build environment like this: https://sourceforge.net/projects/postgresql-mingw-w64/ But according to https://github.com/cyga/www_fdw there is no version of that FDW that works with 9.6 only 9.5. For 9.5 you could download the Windows binaries from: http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/361-Foreign-Data-Wrappers-for-PostgreSQL-9.5-windows.html

Comment: Yes that was the problem. I installed mingw and msys and postgresql server packages. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved when I installed mingw64 and msys. I compiled postgresql server in my machine and I used the:

build packages for www_fdw:

http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/361-Foreign-Data-Wrappers-for-PostgreSQL-9.5-windows.html

and copied the related folders in the related directories (bin, lib, share) in postgresql folder.

Thanks a-horse-with-no-name!